# SQL select all rows where at least one column is not NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im looking for a best way to select all rows where at least one of these column

```
job_start, title, visit_hours, name, leave_start and leave_end
```

has a value, and at least one uniq first_name row must be selected from below table

The result should exclude row 1 and 7

[image]

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but wouldn't you just do something like `SELECT * FROM <TableName> WHERE first_name IS NOT NULL AND (job_start IS NOT NULL OR title IS NOT NULL OR visit_hours IS NOT NULL OR name IS NOT NULL OR leave_start IS NOT NULL OR leave_end IS NOT NULL)`? That should select all values from each row where at least one of those columns has a value.

Comment: @CaleBanfield I believe that the trick is row 4, where `u4` has all `null` for the desired columns, but no other row is shown for that `first_name` so that row should be returned with the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `row_number()` to return at least 1 row per `first_name`, prioritizing those with a non-`null` column first.

```
select *
from (
  select t.*
    , row_number() over (
        partition by first_name 
        order by case when job_start is not null
                or title is not null
                or visit_hours is not null
                or name is not null
                or leave_start is not null
                or leave_end is not null
          then 0 
          else 1 
          end
        ) as rn
  from t
) sub
where rn = 1
  or (job_start is not null
    or title is not null
    or visit_hours is not null
    or name is not null
    or leave_start is not null
    or leave_end is not null
  )
```

Comment: The outer `where` condition can just be `where rn = 1`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I believe that would exclude two of the 5th, 6th and 8th rows (for `u1`), when OP wants both returned (based on only rows 1 and 7 being excluded).

Comment: Thanks this is what Im after

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, you can do this using `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (first_name) t.*
from t
order by first_name,
         (case when job_start is not null or
                    title is not null or
                    visit_hours is not null or
                    name is not null or
                    leave_start is not null or
                    leave_end is not null
               then 0 
               else 1 
          end)
```

Comment: Thanks, in my case I don't really want to distinct on first name, cuz I still want to keep row 5 and 6, which have duplicate first_name, is there a way to do that? originally I thought about having where clause on all columns with OR except  first_name.